$a_k = \frac{k}{(k - 1)^{4/3} + k^{4/3} + (k+1)^{4/3}}$ then give upperlimit of this $s_n = \sum_{k=1}^n a_k$. How to proceed using AM-Gm? What to do?
If $$a_k = \frac{k}{(k - 1)^{4/3} + k^{4/3} + (k+1)^{4/3}} $$
then give upper limit of this
$$s_n = \sum_{k=1}^n a_k.$$
I have tried using AM-GM but couldn't manage a tight upper bound for the summation $s_n$. what to do?

Mathjax tutorial: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Try showing that $(k - 1)^{4/3}  + (k + 1)^{4/3}  \ge 2k^{4/3}$ and hence that $
a_k  \le \frac{1}{3}\frac{1}{{k^{1/3} }}$. From there, try showing $
s_n  \le \frac{1}{2}n^{2/3} $.

How tight do you need the bound to be?  Does Gary's bound above suffice?

i think there is more precise bound tighter than. Garry's

@SwastikSanyal Note that $s_n  = \frac{1}{2}n^{2/3}+\mathcal{O}(1)$, so my bound is rather sharp.

@SwastikSanyal Please check https://math.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers

@SwastikSanyal Please check https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234

@Gary Sir please add in your answer how to show that k-1 and k+1 thing >= 2k thing along with the way to apply summation on 1/k^(1/3) for bound for s(n)

@DarshitSharma By the convexity of $x\mapsto x^{4/3}$, $\frac{{(k - 1)^{4/3}  + (k + 1)^{4/3} }}{2} \ge (k - 1 + k + 1)^{4/3}  = k^{4/3}$. Then $$
\sum\limits_{k = 1}^n {\frac{1}{3}\frac{1}{{k^{1/3} }}}  = \frac{1}{3}\sum\limits_{k = 1}^n {\int_{k - 1}^k {\frac{1}{{k^{1/3} }}{\rm d}t} }  \le \frac{1}{3}\sum\limits_{k = 1}^n {\int_{k - 1}^k {\frac{1}{{t^{1/3} }}{\rm d}t} }  = \frac{1}{3}\int_0^n {\frac{1}{{t^{1/3} }}{\rm d}t}  = \frac{1}{2}n^{2/3} .
$$

@Gary Ohk sir. And about the sum....isn't there a way without using integration? Like telescoping or something?

@DarshitSharma I don't know. You can think about it. And of course I meant $\left( {\frac{{k - 1 + k + 1}}{2}} \right)^{4/3}  = k^{4/3} $.

@gary ok sir....will write if I get a new way to solve.

I provided a method to determine an upper bound for $s_n$ in the comments. Now, I will demonstrate that this bound is sharp by deriving an asymptotic formula for $s_n$. Firstly,
$$
\frac{k}{{(k - 1)^{4/3}  + k^{4/3}  + (k + 1)^{4/3} }} = \frac{1}{3}\frac{1}{{k^{1/3} }} - \frac{4}{{81}}\frac{1}{{k^{7/3} }} + \frac{2}{{729}}\frac{1}{{k^{13/3} }} + \mathcal{O}\!\left( {\frac{1}{{k^{19/3} }}} \right).\tag{1}
$$
Consequently,
\begin{align*}
&\sum\limits_{k = 1}^n {\left[ {\frac{k}{{(k - 1)^{4/3}  + k^{4/3}  + (k + 1)^{4/3} }} - \frac{1}{3}\frac{1}{{k^{1/3} }}} \right]} \\ &= \sum\limits_{k = 1}^\infty  {\left[ {\frac{k}{{(k - 1)^{4/3}  + k^{4/3}  + (k + 1)^{4/3} }} - \frac{1}{3}\frac{1}{{k^{1/3} }}} \right]}  + \mathcal{O}\!\left( {\frac{1}{{n^{4/3} }}} \right)
\end{align*}
as $n\to+\infty$. Thus, utilising this answer,
\begin{align*}
s_n & = \frac{1}{3}\sum\limits_{k = 1}^n {\frac{1}{{k^{1/3} }}}  + \sum\limits_{k = 1}^n {\left[ {\frac{k}{{(k - 1)^{4/3}  + k^{4/3}  + (k + 1)^{4/3} }} - \frac{1}{3}\frac{1}{{k^{1/3} }}} \right]} 
\\ & = \frac{1}{3}\sum\limits_{k = 1}^n {\frac{1}{{k^{1/3} }}}  + \sum\limits_{k = 1}^\infty  {\left[ {\frac{k}{{(k - 1)^{4/3}  + k^{4/3}  + (k + 1)^{4/3} }} - \frac{1}{3}\frac{1}{{k^{1/3} }}} \right]}  + \mathcal{O}\!\left( {\frac{1}{{n^{4/3} }}} \right)
\\ & = \frac{1}{2}n^{2/3}  + C + \frac{1}{6}\frac{1}{{n^{1/3} }} + \mathcal{O}\!\left( {\frac{1}{{n^{4/3} }}} \right)
\end{align*}
as $n\to+\infty$, where
$$
C = \tfrac{1}{3}\zeta \!\left( {\tfrac{1}{3}} \right) + \sum\limits_{k = 1}^\infty  {\left[ {\frac{k}{{(k - 1)^{4/3}  + k^{4/3}  + (k + 1)^{4/3} }} - \frac{1}{3}\frac{1}{{k^{1/3} }}} \right]} 
$$
and $\zeta$ denotes the Riemann zeta function. Using equation $(1)$, we obtain a refined expression for $C$ that exhibits better convergence properties:
\begin{align*}
C = \tfrac{1}{3}\zeta\! \left( {\tfrac{1}{3}} \right) &- \tfrac{4}{{81}}\zeta\! \left( {\tfrac{7}{3}} \right) + \tfrac{2}{{729}}\zeta\! \left( {\tfrac{{13}}{3}} \right) \\ &+ \sum\limits_{k = 1}^\infty  {\left[ {\frac{k}{{(k - 1)^{4/3}  + k^{4/3}  + (k + 1)^{4/3} }} - \frac{1}{3}\frac{1}{{k^{1/3} }} + \frac{4}{{81}}\frac{1}{{k^{7/3} }} - \frac{2}{{729}}\frac{1}{{k^{13/3} }}} \right]} .
\end{align*}
Specifically, we find that $C = -0.394030821643744 \ldots$. If needed, it is possible to obtain higher terms in the asymptotics of $s_n$. For instance, an analysis similar to the one presented here yields
$$
s_n  \sim \frac{1}{2}\left( {n + \tfrac{1}{2}} \right)^{2/3}  + C + \frac{1}{{24\left( {n + \frac{1}{2}} \right)^{1 + 1/3} }} - \frac{{47}}{{7776\left( {n + \frac{1}{2}} \right)^{3 + 1/3} }} +  \ldots ,
$$
as $n\to+\infty$.

the value of the constant helps

+1 absolutely fantastic answer...But sir please add on about the steps to find the upperbound. Please sir

Too long for a comment
(i) Using Gary's idea, we have (by Bernoulli inequality or other ways)
$a_k \le \frac13 k^{-1/3}$ for all $k\ge 1$. We can prove that (by Bernoulli inequality), for all $k \ge 1$,
$$a_k \le \frac13 k^{-1/3} \le \frac12 k^{2/3} - \frac12(k-1)^{2/3}. \tag{1}$$
Thus, if $n \ge N$, we have
$$s_n \le \sum_{k=1}^{N-1} a_k + \sum_{k=N}^n \Big(\frac12 k^{2/3} - \frac12(k-1)^{2/3}\Big)$$
$$= \frac12n^{2/3} - \Big(\frac12(N-1)^{2/3} - \sum_{k=1}^{N-1} a_k\Big). \tag{2}$$
For example, if $N = 2$, (3) gives $s_n \le \frac12 n^{2/3} - \frac12 + \frac{1}{1 + 2^{4/3}} \approx \frac12 n^{2/3} - 0.2159$ for all $n\ge 2$; if $N = 6$, (3) gives
$s_n \le \frac12 n^{2/3} - 0.2938....$ for all $n \ge 6$.
(ii) Let $f(n) := \frac12n^{2/3} - s_n$. Using (1), we have
$$f(n + 1) - f(n) = \frac12(n + 1)^{2/3} - \frac12n^{2/3} - a_{n+1} \ge 0.$$
Also, we can prove that $s_n > \frac12 n^{2/3} - C$ for some constant $C > 0$. Thus, $f(n) \le C$.
Thus, $L := \lim_{n\to \infty} f(n)$ exists (finite).
Thus, $s_n = \frac12n^{2/3} - L + o(1)$.

Do you need to assume $n\ge N$?

@Gary Thanks for the suggestion. I think I need to edit the answer.

As $$\frac{k}{(k - 1)^{4/3} + k^{4/3} + (k+1)^{4/3}} < \frac{k}{(k - 1)^{4/3} + (k+1)^{2/3}(k-1)^{2/3} + (k+1)^{4/3}}$$
Let $$S=\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{k}{(k - 1)^{4/3} + (k+1)^{2/3}(k-1)^{2/3} + (k+1)^{4/3}}$$
$$=\sum\frac{k((k+1)^{2/3}-(k-1)^{2/3})}{(k+1)^2-(k-1)^2}$$
$$=\sum\frac{(k+1)^{2/3}-(k-1)^{2/3}}{4}$$
$$=\frac{(n+1)^{2/3}+n^{2/3}-1}{4}$$
So we can conclude that $$\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{k}{(k - 1)^{4/3} + k^{4/3} + (k+1)^{4/3}}<\frac{(n+1)^{2/3}+n^{2/3}-1}{4}$$

your solution is simple and amazing. Thank you so much.
